# How to check if a string is a measurement

Tags: macros

I'd like a command to check if a string is a measurement, e.g. `1cm`. Checking if the string contains `cm` seems like it could go wrong easily. I seem to remember seeing an example someone had made somewhere, but I can't find it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\IsMeasurement}{m}{
    % magic
}

\begin{document}
    \IsMeasurement{1pt} % should output true, yes, 1, or similar
    \IsMeasurement{1ptolemy} % should output false, no, 0, or similar
\end{document}
```

My current approach is to test the last two characters, like so, and hope no cases come up that produce false positives:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\LastTwo}{m}{%
    \tl_item:nn { #1 } { -2 }%
    \tl_item:nn { #1 } { -1 }%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\IsMeasurement}{m}{
    \str_case:nnF { #1 } {
        { cm } { 1 }
        { mm } { 1 } 
        { pt } { 1 }
    } { 0 }
}

\begin{document}
    \IsMeasurement{cm} % works
    \LastTwo{22cm} % outputs cm, as desired
    \IsMeasurement{\LastTwo{cm}} % doesn't work
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see whether the input matches a regular expression.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\islengthTF}{mmm}
 {
  \mjc_islength:enn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mjc_islength:nnn
 {
  \regex_match:nnTF
   {
    \A                           % whole token list
    [-+]?((\d+\.?\d*)|(\.\d+))   % a number https://stackoverflow.com/a/42629198/923955
    \s*                          % optional spaces
    (sp|pt|bp|dd|pc|cc|mm|cm|in) % legal TeX units
    \Z                           % whole token list
   }
   { #1 }
   { #2 } % it matches
   { #3 } % no match
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \mjc_islength:nnn { e }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\mylength}{12pt}

\begin{document}

\islengthTF{\mylength}{TRUE}{FALSE} (true)

\islengthTF{12pt}{TRUE}{FALSE} (true)

\islengthTF{12ptolemy}{TRUE}{FALSE} (false)

\islengthTF{.12cm}{TRUE}{FALSE} (true)

\islengthTF{..12cm}{TRUE}{FALSE} (false)

\islengthTF{2.1 in}{TRUE}{FALSE} (true)

\islengthTF{-2. cm}{TRUE}{FALSE} (true)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Description:

- `\A` stands for “start of the input”
- `[-+]?` means zero or one characters among `-` or `+`
- `\d+\.?\d*` means one or more digits optionally followed by a period and other digits
- `\.d+` means a period followed by one or more digits
- `\s*` means optional spaces
- `(sp|...|in)` looks for one among the legal two-letter symbols for units
- `\Z` stands for “end of the input”

Actually the part `(\.\d+)` could be `(\.d*)` because `.cm` is legal in TeX to denote zero centimeters. Let's not be too esoteric. Similarly, TeX allows for any number of optional signs at the beginning, but this doesn't seem worth allowing in your case.